# View uses language SQL condition for untranslatable fields

Tags: views, theming, 8, nodes

I have got an issue with `views`. The problem is that a view uses the SQL WHERE condition while retrieving data from DB.

Here is the example to explain the problem.

I have a custom node type - `work`. It has a custom field `field_work_sort_order`  with the `Users may translate this field` flag unchecked.

But the view`s SQL query is following

```
SELECT node__field_work_sort_order.field_work_sort_order_value AS node__field_work_sort_order_field_work_sort_order_value, node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM 
{node_field_data} node_field_data
LEFT JOIN {node__field_work_sort_order} node__field_work_sort_order ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_work_sort_order.entity_id AND (node__field_work_sort_order.deleted = '0' AND node__field_work_sort_order.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
WHERE (( (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN  ('', '', '', 'work')) AND (node_field_data.langcode IN  ('en', 'en')) ))
ORDER BY node__field_work_sort_order_field_work_sort_order_value ASC
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

Here is the interesting part

```
 AND node__field_work_sort_order.langcode = node_field_data.langcode)
```

As you can see it compares if the field has the same language as `node_field_data` but as I have already mentioned it is not translatable field.

As a result I have different order of nodes for different languages.

How can I solve the problem ? Is there any solution ? Or maybe this is my fault.

I would be grateful for any help.

**UPDATE**

Here is my full view

[image]

And my enabled language modules

[image]

P.S I have been facing with the language problems for the whole development process. I have asked a lot of questions related to the language problems (@Oleg Videnov you have helped me several times so far) But I found just ways that don't solve problems but just hide them. So all in all language modules and some parts of the Drupal core seem very buggy, and I am wondering if only I have these problems. As far as I am using the latest version and haven't modified any core files.

Comment: could you post the export of the whole view for proper analysis ?

Comment: which langauge modules have you enabled?

Comment: @OlegVidenov I have just added more details, please have a look

Comment: not sure if I am able to assist you without more hands-on collaboration.
if you want enter here..
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/55828/assistance?tab=general

Comment: @OlegVidenov, thanks, I've just joined this room, for now the solution is to make this field translatable and set the order field for translation